# Is the form [What time is + noun-phrase] ungrammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, grammaticality-in-context

This question sprang to mind while I was learning Chinese using an app. To make it clear what sentence I tried to translate, it's:

> 你们上午几点喝茶?

The suggestion answer from the app is

> What time in the morning do you drink tea?

In my opinion the sentence is fine and perhaps I could conclude that the full sentence is

> At what time do you drink tea in the morning?

However, it's just an opinion and I was thinking there's a common phrase when someone asks

> What time is it?

I tried to substitute the "it" with the noun-phrase "you drink in the morning" and this answer wasn't accepted that made me think It's definitely wrong but I don't know the reason. I also have asked this question to my learning group and someone said that my sentence is wrong. Here I want to know more, why is it incorrect? Do I think the sentence construction incorrectly?

Comment: "You drink tea in the morning" is a clause, not a noun phrase. "You" is the subject, "drink" is the conjugated verb, and "in the morning" is an adverbial of time that modifies the whole sentence.

Comment: Try replacing "it" with an actual noun phrase, such as "your flight": "What time is your flight?" Voila! It's perfectly fine.

Comment: You could also say something like "At what time is it that you drink tea in the morning?" although that is a very lengthy, "wordy" way of saying it.

Comment: @stangdon Is it also correct if I remove "that" in that sentence? Is it necessary? By the way, thanks for the answers.

Comment: @user516076  You mean, "At what time is it you drink tea in the morning?"  Yes, that would still be correct.